# How to make an external call to a rest service in another domain

Tags: angularjs, rest, angular-schema-form

I am working with the [Angular Schema Form](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form) framework, using this to create a form which has basic address fields. I have to make a call to external rest service to validate the addresses entered. I have to get the JSON data from a rest service and perform some changes and render them to the page. I have no idea how to do this any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: If the "another domain" part is what you are having a problem with, take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: you can use the $http service provided by angular
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: @charlietfl I don't see this as a duplicate given the question relates to Angular Schema Form and the "duplicate" links to a purely AngularJS based question. Angular Schema Form has it's own add-ons and tools for providing look ups outside of $http.